# PyCUDA / Copperhead doesn't appear to recognise 64-bit machines

Tags: python, boost, cuda, boost-python, pycuda

Two problems I'm having with copperhead at the minute, which I suspect are related.

Running a sample file (samples/axpy.py) generated lots of little warnings, but this one stood out.

```
g++ -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/python2.6 -I/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/copperhead-0.1a1-py2.6.egg/copperhead/include -I/usr/local/cuda/include /tmp/codepy-compiler-cache-v5-uid1000/202478034fea29b82d046b259bd6f43e/module.o /tmp/codepy-compiler-cache-v5-uid1000/fdcb04ede426b146cfce8894e99eeb57/gpu.o -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/cuda/lib -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart -lboost_python-gcc43-mt -lpthread -ldl -lutil -o /tmp/codepy-compiler-cache-v5-uid1000/202478034fea29b82d046b259bd6f43e/codepy.temp.202478034fea29b82d046b259bd6f43e.module.so
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/cuda/lib/libcudart.so when searching for -lcudart
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_python-gcc43-mt
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Few things to notice;

g++ is has correctly picked up the correct CUDA lib dir to use (lib64), but doesn't see libcudart.so in there, which it is.

```
/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so.4.0.12: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
```

Next, boost_python isn't found; I've heard from a few places that this is due to ubuntu breaking a package convention somewhere, and people has said they've fixed it by changing the pycuda configure options, but haven't said what to change it to... ([Example](http://code.google.com/p/copperhead/issues/detail?id=2))

Anyone got any ideas for either the cudart or boot issues?

Answer (score 3):

1. It *is* finding `libcudart`. What you
   are seeing is only an informational
   warning: -L options are
   searched in order and the linker is
   finding the 32 bit version first,
   because you gave
   `-L/usr/local/cuda/lib` before `-L/usr/loca/cuda/lib64`.
2. For the libboost_python problem,
   just link with `-lboost_python`. The
   Ubuntu systems I use (64 bit
   10.04LTS with boost-python 1.40) have a series of cascading symbolic
   links to that canonical 
   library name that make the linker
   find the correct library without any
   further intervention.